# Freeing memory used by unattached DOM nodes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management

As part of my application, I'm putting together a set of small Dom nodes that are not shown all at once. I'm storing them in an internal array.  The user can invoke their display in which case I reparent them to the div that is used to display them.  That's all well and good.  But when it's time to replace all of them with new ones, I want to destroy the old ones (effectively deallocate them).  Otherwise, over time, memory usage could grow exponentially.  How do I force the browser js engine to do this?  Is just setting each of the items in my array of Dom nodes to null enough?  Is there something else I have to do?  Or maybe I don't have to worry about this at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set each item to null, they will be automatically garbage collected.

Comment: Great.  That's what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, setting the items to null should be ok…  Except that some implementation details must be taken care of with Internet Explorer: its handling of circular references is dodgy.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448.aspx

> Circular References—When mutual references are counted between Internet Explorer's COM infrastructure and any scripting engine, objects can leak memory

So you *have* to break circular references in some cases.